# Week view on in-app calendar (Universal Windows Platform / UWP)

Tags: xaml, calendar, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I was wondering if is there a custom view that lets me show a week view (or a day-view) like the Windows 10 Calendar app. I've looked at CalendarView, but it seems not I can show only one week/day, with hour delimiters. I've looked to custom views, but found nothing.

[image: Calendar App Windows 10 - Week View]

In case I must handcraft a custom view, any guidances? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The UWP Calendar control all does NOT support what you want. I wish it did.

Answer (score 0):

I'm developing an open-source [calendar control](https://github.com/gave92/CalendarControl) for UWP. Is also available as nuget package.

It's still pretty basic, but supports week view and event/appointments management. The look and behavior should be easy to adapt to your needs.

Sample usage:

```
<Page xmlns:calendar="using:CalendarControl">
    <Grid>
        <calendar:Calendar Padding="16,0,16,16"
                           CanvasMinHeight="500"
                           CanvasMaxHeight="600" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```